# pad() select to show 2 characters

Tags: mysql, jsp, datetime, jdbc, time

I have a working `select` statement **MySQL** which returns `days`, `hours`, `mins`, `secs` from a duration which is in seconds -

```
SELECT Name, Zone, Duration,
FLOOR(Duration/60/60/24) as days,
FLOOR(Duration/60/60)%24 as hours,
FLOOR(Duration/60)%60 as mins,
Duration%60 as secs
from duration
```

I would like each column to have 2 characters so all the data is `inline` so somehow need to pad any single character with a zero 
    (i.e. if days is 1 then pad / format so days is 01)

I have tried pad() -

```
PAD(FLOOR(Duration/60/60/24),2,0) as days
```

but this results in NULL.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Regards
Ralph

Comment: Why are you trying to do the presentation layer's job inside a SQL query? Don't. get the duration, as is, from the database, and format it in the presentation layer.

Comment: Thanks, though I was trying to avoid having to do a c:set then a fmt: and finally the c:out, unless there's an easier way?

Comment: It's not about being easy. It's about being right. The persistence layer is supposed to return structured data that you can easily work with, not pre-formatted text. And the presentation layer is the one responsible for displaying the data the best way for your users. What if you decide to display the duration in a human form (like, for example "a few seconds", or "3 hours"). Clearly the database can't do that. And you shouldn't have to change the persistence layer if you change your formatting or i18n requirements.

Comment: Not to mention that, if you create some tag or function to properly format a duration, you can use it wherever it comes from (the database, Java code, whatever), and you don't have to change every SQL query that returns a duration.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for [`SEC_TO_TIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) and [`SUBSTR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr).
To get `01:02:03` use `SEC_TO_TIME(3723)`.

To get the zero-padded numbers for HH, MM, SS, do this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(SEC_TO_TIME(3723),1,2) HH, 
       SUBSTR(SEC_TO_TIME(3723),4,2) MM, 
       SUBSTR(SEC_TO_TIME(3723),7,2) SS
```

If you have an integer, say `7`, and you want the text string `07`, you can use [`LPAD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad):

```
 SELECT LPAD(7,2,'0')
```

**Pro tip**: using `TIME`, `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP`, and/or `DATETIME` data types in your tables is really good practice, because it allows you to  explot all the date arithmetic offered by MySQL. JDBC offers clean conversions from those database-side data types to Java data types, making their manipulation almost seamless from database to program.

**Pro tip**: Read these two MySQL reference manual pages all the way through every week for a month or so. Knowing the functions available to you makes your job easier.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Thanks O Jones, though see my other post on attempts to then CONCAT or CONCAT_WS which always produces a NULL and SEC_TO_TIME which is limited to 838 hours.